# SqlLite. Как воспользоваться оператором like?

Tags: sql, sqlite3

Всем привет!
Пытаюсь воспользоваться like'ом в sqllite и не получается сделать выборку из поля **param**
При селекте это поле показывается как:

`b'{"param1":"1","param2":"2"}'`

И если написать запрос вида, то ничего не вернется((

`select * from table where param like "%2%"`

По другим полям like работает нормально.
Подскажите, как лечить

Важное замечание - использую либу для питона sqlite3

Формат поля **param text**

Comment: Строки в sql через одинарные кавычки пишутся: `select * from table where param like '%2%'`, пример https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-like/

Comment: Спасио, хорошее замечание) только дело не в этом( вот оригинал  ```cursor.execute("SELECT *  FROM table where param like ?",["%"+"2"+"%"])```

Comment: Используя биндинг (`?`) вы получите экранирование значений, возможно в этом проблема, попробуйте: `cursor.execute("SELECT *  FROM table where param like '%' || ? || '%'", ["2"])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположу, что при вставке в БД данным присваивается
привязка к типу (англ.
«[*type affinity*](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)»)
`BLOB`, а не `TEXT`. Со значениями
с этой привязкой оператор `LIKE` либо не работает
вообще, либо работает странно. Можете попробовать
явное преобразование:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CAST(param AS TEXT) LIKE '%2%';
```

Либо сразу вставляйте данные с привязкой
`TEXT`. Как это делать должно быть написано
в документации к вашей библиотеке.

Либо использовать расширение
[*JSON1*](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html)
для работы с *JSON*-данными.

Comment: чудо - это работает! :) спасибо!